# Specify destination server instance in request Azure Load Balancer

Tags: sql-server, azure, load-balancing, azure-storage, multiple-instances

Hi I have an server which hosts an azure load balancer. There are multiple server instances the balancer manages. How do i get the sever instance id's from the host ip for the load balancer. Is there a default request to use to get this information. Are there some default headers i must set when sending a request. 
I primarily want to inform the load balancer to send my request to specific server instances.

I only have the public ip of the load balancer and i need to get all the server instances and send my http request to specific server instances. Can i do all this with with only the ip address? I am new with this

Comment: You can't do this with the Azure LB

Comment: @CtrlDot which of the above cant i do.  Find out the server instance ids runing on the host? Or tell the LB to send request to specific servers?

Comment: Both.  You can query the backend servers via the Azure portal, but you can't get that info from the LB itself.  In order to route to a specific server, you'd probably have to fool around with App Gateway to see if it had that specific capability (using some sort of header like you suggested)

Comment: Oh ok. So you are saying i need access to Azure portal (The LB) account for this to be likely? Okay

Comment: Yeah, Azure LB is a layer 4 device, so it won't be able to do some of the more advanced load balancing features.  There are ways to work around this, but it really depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Load balancer with multiple server instances, do you mean your create multiple Azure VMs and a Load balancer in Azure **ARM** module? If yes, we can use **PowerShell** to get the information about VMs, like this:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress | ?{ $_.ipaddress -eq "52.168.145.1" } | select name, resourcegroupname
$pip = Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name mypublicip -ResourceGroupName lb
$lbname = ($pip.IpConfiguration.Id -split '/')[8]
$lbinfo = Get-AzureRmLoadBalancer -Name $lbname -ResourceGroupName lb
$backendips = $lbinfo.BackendAddressPools.BackendIpConfigurations.id
$nics = foreach($id in $backendips){($id -split '/')[8]}
$vms = foreach($nic in $nics){$test = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $nic -ResourceGroupName lb ; $vmname =($test.VirtualMachine.id -split '/')[-1];$vmaddress=$test.IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress;$results = [pscustomobject]@{'VMname'=$vmname;'PrivateAddress'=$vmaddress};$results }
$vms
```

Here is the test in my lab:

[image]

Comment: In this example I need to login to the Azure account right? I can  not achieve this without logging in?

Comment: @flexxxit Yes, we should login Azure account, then we can list the information.